# Dataset and SQL Server CE in .net 4

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, dataset, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to build a SQL Server CE table structure dynamically using a dataset as the temporary table structure...

Is there a `SqlConnection` string that will work with SQL Server CE?

There used to be a `SqlCeConnection`...but I don't find that in the 4.0 framework? Has something replaced this?

If the answer is L2S or Entity Framework... can I add columns to SQL Server CE tables at runtime?

If so... how?

Answer (score 3):

There still is a SqlCeConnection class. Do you have a reference to the System.Data.SqlServerCe assembly?

Comment: I did have one... turns out I had two and chose the older.